# Element move down when text is added

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with elements. When I type any text in any place inside `search_groups_wrapper`, the right colum fall to the bottom. If there is no text, it is displayed as should be. What is the problem?

Here is jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/csYU8/ with problem. Remove 'Here is some text' and element will move top.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/csYU8/4/ has cleaner HTML.  You can update your question with this fiddle

Comment: Well, you removed <!--, --> but it does not affect the problem.

Comment: I know,  it was getting very difficult to understand. So cleaned the HTML.  When you share a fiddle,  it's always good to avoid unnecessary comments and give proper indentation.

Comment: see my answer. add `float:left;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find what causes this but I found a solution:

Just add the styles below to your `#search_wrapper`

```
top:0;
position:absolute;
```

**CSS**

```
#search_wrapper
{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/csYU8/4/)

Comment: Hi @user3365404. if you think this answer helped you, don't forget to click the green check button to mark it as an accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `display:inline-block` you should use `float:left` property. and to clear the float you can use `clear:left` on parent div.

or you want to still use the `display: inline-block`.

```
#search_groups_wrapper
{
display:inline-block;
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:0;
width:70%;
position:relative;
top:0;
vertical-align:top; /*I've just added this line*/
}
```

Here is the another working Demo . http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/csYU8/7/

```
#search_groups_wrapper {
    border: 0 none;
    display: inline-block; /*Better Remove this line and add float left*/
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 70%;
}

#existing_groups_wrapper {
    border: 0 none;
    display: inline-block; /*Better Remove this line and add float left*/
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 30%;
}
```

Here is a Demo. http://jsfiddle.net/csYU8/

Comment: I cannot remove display: inline-block;, because I need 2 elements one after another in one line. With float left, I get them floated, but not in one line.

Comment: okay just updated my answer now. I've added only `vertical-align:top;` on this id `#search_groups_wrapper`. check the Demo link. http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/csYU8/7/

Answer (score 1):

Add `align: left` to your `search_groups_wrapper` and `existing_groups_wrapper`.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/csYU8/6/)